# React Bootstrap adding into a component - cards

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I would love if the cards were shown 4 per row on the page..
I get this error:

Failed to compile
./src/components/MyDishes.js
SyntaxError: /Users/adiskop/zestie-frontend/src/components/MyDishes.js: Unexpected token, expected "}" (27:12)

25 |                   
26 |               ))

> 27 |             : null;
> |             ^
> 28 |
> 29 |     return dishCards;
> 30 | };

````
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MyDishes = props => {
    const dishCards =
        props.dishes.length > 0
            ? props.dishes.map(d => (
              <Row xs={1} md={2} className="g-4">
              {Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, idx) => (
                <Col>
                  <Card key={d.id} style={{ width: '30rem' }}>
                      <Card.Img variant="top" src={d.attributes.picture} />
                      <Card.Body>
                          <Card.Title>{d.attributes.name}</Card.Title>
                          <Card.Text>
                            Possibly some text here
                          </Card.Text>
                          <Link to={`/dishes/${d.id}`}>
                              <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                          </Link>
                      </Card.Body>
                  </Card>
                  </Col>
              ))
            : null;

    return dishCards;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        dishes: state.myDishes
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyDishes); ```
````

Comment: But where are you using `Card` exactly? You imported but aren’t using it in render

Comment: Could you also specify what exactly is happening? Is it not working and if yes, then what is your expectation? Are you running into any errors? Where exactly is the error coming from?

Comment: I tried to place it in so many ways.. I just gave up eventually. I couldn't figure out where to put it and make it work. I'm a total beginner ;/ First I

Comment: I would love if someone show me how to implement it into my code here. I tried every possible way it seems like. but I am a beginner.. so I probably made a 100 mistakes..

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I am very much lost on how to implement it.. what they show as examples in the documentation didn't work for me. I had to just go back to my original code because it got so messy. so maybe you could show me how

Comment: Update your question with what you tried specifically using Card. You copied one of the examples, put it inside your map function, and put your variables into the specific card sub elements right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { React } from 'react';
import { Card, Button, CardGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyDishes = props => {
    const { dishes } = props;

    return (
        <CardGroup>
            {dishes.length > 0 &&
                dishes.map(d => (
                    <Card key={d.id} style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={d.attributes.picture} />
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>{d.attributes.name}</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>Possibly some text here</Card.Text>
                            <Link to={`/dishes/${d.id}`}>
                                <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                            </Link>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                ))}
        </CardGroup>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        dishes: state.myDishes
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyDishes);
```

This should be working, if this does not render the card then this means your dishes redux state is empty.

Comment: You're a genius.. thank you! and how can i make them look nice on the page , like the Card Groups - on ReactBootstrap ?

Comment: You can wrap your MyDishes component with <CardGroup> wrapper. Here is the link to documentation: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#card-groups. Whats propably worth to mention is that using css to style would be also helpful. Please approve the answer if this helps you - thanks

Comment: It wasn't successful unfortunately..

Comment: This shold be working unless you applied documentation wrong. I'll edit my main post in a second to show you how to wrap it correctly.

Comment: It worked , but they ended in one long column .. and I want them to be nicely spread horizontally as well..

Comment: This is styling issue and not related to the original question. You could have a look into bootstrap grid https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ or check what flexbox is - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: Okay, thank you!! very much

Comment: Your welcome. Please upvote the original answer - thank you!